# TypeScript generic not picked up

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an interface for an event handler with a single generic parameter which is a string extracted
from a type with all the possible events, for some reason typescript does not recognise
the actual type when I'm using the generic parameter as the index

```
type Events = {
  test: { hello: number }
}

interface EventHandler<E extends keyof Events> {
  getName(): string;

  handle(event: Events[E]): Promise<void>;
}

class DummyHandler implements EventHandler<'test'> {
  getName() { return '' }

  async handle(event) {
    // event is of type any
  }
}
```

[PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAzlAvFA3gWAFBRTAQrABc2UAFhADa0D2FiArgLYBGEATlAL74BefAEtkPAGYBDAMbR4SYAAkpiACa0eAHhhQIAD2Lq0AawggGE2AmQoAfNnyEA5hGAA5KWwgAKAJQUpNxizgDc%20E7Uqhq%20EDbk1oooANowALoBUAAK3AxsIigQWnAMImp24XhC%20DK0UihoACLsbCAq6pq8Imxgmt62icjtMdxaAOTEpGMOuARQrh5evn6U3G4s3IhQY2P8EXP1IIgyUR2x8SuzhIRxigB0NPQMkUJ8QA)

Comment: [Simpler example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIA84FsAOAbCAHgBUA+ZAbwFgAoZe5LCMACwHsATACggDcJwALmTEAlMN5tgHANy0AvrVoI8cAM5q0mXAQDCqjcmA6ITcJozZ8RNWCigA5uWp0GTVpx79woyrQYByAhsIGpsBAB0eGwOXgJgonKu9Io08kA). As far as I can tell, TypeScript just doesn't do that (apply the parameter types from the interface to the class method automatically).

Comment: Never mind. I read the other question, this is indeed a tricky problem for TypeScript. Thanks.